# DTMF Tone Detection during incoming oncall in Blackberrry java

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I would like to know whether we could receive the DTMF tones in blackberry java.Suppose,i am getting a call,and once i accept the call,is it possible to detect the keys that the other person is pressing during our call.
I want to know any possiblity is available in bb java.

Answer (score 0):

There was a method to retrieve DTMF tones:

[PhoneCall.getDTMFTones](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2.1api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/PhoneCall.html#getDTMFTones%28%29)

But I think it only worked for the tones sent from the device.
It was removed from the docs in 4.3, and from the API in 4.5. You can try compiling with 4.3 and see what happens.